# No incoming connections after upgrade to 20.10

Tags: networking, upgrade, ssh, apache2

I am unable to connect to my box via Apache or ssh since upgrading to Ubunutu 20.10 beta.
Both show as running, but no service:

```
    mark@marks-linux-box:~$ sudo service ssh status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: e>
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-10-23 18:01:42 BST; 4min 46s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 1563 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19091)
     Memory: 2.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─1563 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Oct 23 18:01:41 marks-linux-box systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell serve>
Oct 23 18:01:42 marks-linux-box sshd[1563]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 23 18:01:42 marks-linux-box sshd[1563]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Oct 23 18:01:42 marks-linux-box systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.

mark@marks-linux-box:~$ sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-10-23 18:02:02 BST; 4min 59s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
   Main PID: 2913 (apache2)
      Tasks: 129 (limit: 19091)
     Memory: 42.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─2913 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─2914 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─2915 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Oct 23 18:01:41 marks-linux-box systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 23 18:02:02 marks-linux-box systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I am using this box to write this question, so it definitely is able to connect to the internet, etc.

Comment: You can see my website is down by going to juglugs dot com

Comment: perhaps the upgrade enabled the firewall. What does 'sudo ufw status' show?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that during the upgrade, my external IP address had changed. A quick Google revealed the correct IP address and I was able to connect to ssh and my website.

I don't understand how/why the external IP address changed though?

Comment: The lease can run out or the connection disrupted.  Unless you have a static ip address, a new ip can be assigned.